# show big numbers (double value) in pie chart using MpAndroidChart

Tags: android, double, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using a pie chart in my activity. When I set a big value into the entries, it doesn't show the value correctly.

For example:

My value is **627050000** but the chart shows is **627049986**,

or

my value is **477470000** but the chart shows is **477470016**.

Here's my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    double num1 = 627050000 ;
    double num2 = 477470000 ;

    setupPieChart();
}

private void setupPieChart() {

    List<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();

    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry((float) num1 , "num1"));
    pieEntries.add(new PieEntry((float) num2 , "num2"));

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries , "numbers");

    PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
    PieChart pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleAlpha(1);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

    //add legend to chart

    Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE);
    legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
    legend.setDirection(Legend.LegendDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    legend.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);

    //add colors to dataset

    ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add(Color.CYAN);
    colors.add(Color.GREEN);
    colors.add(Color.RED);

    dataSet.setColors(colors);

    pieChart.setData(data);
    pieChart.animateY(1000);
    pieChart.invalidate();
}
```

I read about `ValueFormatter` class also using BigDecimal but I didn't understand.
Please help and explain in a simple way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you convert double numbers into float. MPAndroidChart will draw an entry with a float value. You define `double num1 = 627050000;` but you store it as `new PieEntry((float) num1 , "num1")`

Note that:

> float: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point....use a float (instead of double) if you need to save
>   memory in large arrays of floating point numbers. This data type
>   should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that,
>   you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead
>
> double: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754
>   floating point. **For decimal values**, this data type is generally
>   the default choice. As mentioned above, this data type should never be
>   used for precise values, such as currency.

([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html))

In the aforementioned conversion you lose in the precision of the number.
Define your values as float instead of double

Comment: thanks. but i think the problem is  related to the library because i added a toast to show the value of num1 and num2  after casting to float and it was correct. although these numbers are just for test and I get numbers from sqlite table which are doubles.

Comment: how can i use big decimal or flaot here ? most of the numbers in my app are doubles

Comment: float num1 = 627050000 ; float num2 = 477470000 ;

Comment: are you still getting the same values as before?

Comment: no i set    float num1 = 627050000 ;  . then     pieEntries.add(new PieEntry(num1 , "num1"));     bud still doesnt work .